# derivative of the inverse of a function

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

Can you please help if I'm calculating this correctly?
$$\frac  {\delta} {\delta \beta}  [\text{ln}(g^{-1}(\alpha + \beta x_i))] 
= \frac {x_i (g'(g^{-1}(\alpha + \beta x_i)))} {g^{-1}(\alpha + \beta x_i)} $$

I'm not sure if this can be simplified further.

I also need help in calculating the second derivative with respect to $\beta$

Comment: No, $(g^{-1}(x))'=1/g'(g^{-1}(x))$, not $g'(g^{-1}(x))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's incorrect. 
From the differentiation rules
$$
[f^{-1}(x)]'=\{f'[f^{-1}(x)]\}^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
\left[\ln(f(x))\right]'=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$

we have

$$
D\equiv\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\{\ln[f^{-1}(g(\beta))]\}=\frac{[f^{-1}(g(\beta))]'}{f^{-1}(g(\beta))}=\frac{\{f'[f^{-1}(g(\beta))]\}^{-1}g'(\beta)}{f^{-1}(g(\beta))}
$$

so

$$
D=\frac{1}{f'[f^{-1}(g(\beta))]}\frac{g'(\beta)}{f^{-1}(g(\beta))}
$$

if $g(\beta)=\alpha + \beta x_i$ then

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\{\ln[f^{-1}(\alpha + \beta x_i)]\}=\frac{1}{f'[f^{-1}(\alpha + \beta x_i)]}\frac{x_i}{f^{-1}(\alpha + \beta x_i)}
$$

Comment: Thank you...  My next question is , how do you then take the second derivative with respect to $\beta$

Comment: Well, you apply the product rule $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$, where $u=\{f'[f^{-1}(\alpha+\beta x_i)]\}^{-1}$ and $v=x_i[f^{-1}(\alpha+\beta x_i)]^{-1}$. Don't forget to use the chain rule for $u$!

Comment: Thanks, do you mean the reciprocal rule and then the product rule?